# I can't type the '%' (percentage) character in my mac terminal

Tags: terminal

Just recently, I notice that while using my mac terminal I can't type in the '%' character.

I can use any other character using the same key, for example '5' and '∞' (option+5), but when I want to use '%' (shift+5) I get the error terminal sound.

If I try to copy and paste text with a '%' included, it will copy all the text except for the '%'. If I connect to a server using ssh, ‘%’ works perfectly.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Try running `stty sane`.

Comment: Hi @NimeshNeema. Thanks for the replay. I tried `stty sane`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you edited any of your configuration files?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen not really. 
I've only worked in .bash_profile.

Comment: Might be it. Show us all the changes you’ve made.

Comment: Also what do you get with the command `locale`?

Comment: from `locale` I get:

`LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`

Answer (score 3):

The problem was in the `.inputrc` file in my home directory.
The first line of this file was like this:

`% Cnd down arrows cycle through commands that match the start of a line`

I had to changed the '%' at the beginning for a '#'. 
Still I don't know why that line had the percentage instead.